# Number of partitions containing $k$ occurrences of a given number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the ordered partitions of $N$ with size $m$ ($m \leq N$), that is, the set $\mathcal{P}_m^N$ of all vectors $\vec{n} \in \mathbb{N}^m$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m n_i = N$. In how many of these partitions the number $n$ appears $k$ times?

In other words, I am interested in the function $f_{k,m}^N(n) = \sum_{\vec{n} \in \mathcal{P}_m^N }  \mathbf{1}(  \sum_{i=1}^{m} \delta_{n n_i} = k)$.

A simpler quantity I am interested in is the total number of occurrences of a given number among ordered partitions of a certain size:  $F_{m}^N(n) = \sum_{\vec{n} \in \mathcal{P}_m^N }    \sum_{i=1}^{m} \delta_{n n_i}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to compose the corresponding bivariate generating function. Let, in your notation,
$$F_m^{(n)}(z,u) = F(z,u) = \sum_{N=0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^\infty f_{k,m}^N(n) z^N u^k.$$
Then it is not hard to see that 
$$
F(z,u) = \left(\sum_{j\ge 1,j\neq n} z^j + u z^n \right)^m = \left(\frac{z}{1-z} + (u-1)z^n \right)^m.
$$ 
Now you can easily find $F_m^N(n)$: 
$$
F_m^N(n) = [z^N]F'_u(z,u)|_{u=1} = m [z^N]\left(\frac{z}{1-z} + (u-1)z^n \right)^{m-1}z^n\Big|_{u=1} = m [z^{N-n}]\frac{z^{m-1}}{(1-z)^{m-1}} = m{N-n -1 \choose m-2}.
$$
Here $[z^N]$ means the coefficient near $z^N$ in the function that follows.

To find $f_{k,m}^N(n)$, you may use an alternative approach (which is easier, I believe). Notice that $f_{k,m}^N(n) = {m \choose k}g_{N-kn,m-k}(n)$, where $g_{s,r}(n)$ is the number of compositions (ordered partitions) of $s$ into $r$ summands different from $n$. The corresponding generating function 
$$
G^{(n)}_r(z) = \sum_{s\ge 1} g_{s,r}(n)z^s
$$
is easily seen to be equal to
$$
G^{(n)}_r(z) = \left(\frac{z}{1-z} - z^n\right)^r,
$$
whence $g_{s,r}(n)$ is computable as a sum of products of some binomial coefficients.

Comment: On second thought, the alternative approach is pretty much the same, but I'll leave it anyway.